# How to use constants in angularjs defined in same file

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to angular js. Is it possible to reuse the constants defined in the same file like below. If not please let me know a better way to reuse the defined constants. My intention behind this is I should be able to use LoginQuery.url in my service instead of concatenating.

```
angular.module('myApp.constants', []).
constant('ServerConfig', {
    'url': 'http://localhost:3000/'
}).
constants('LoginQuery', {
        'url': ServerConfig.url + "/login"
    }
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to do this the following way:

```js
angular.module('myApp.constants', [])
.constant('urlsConst', (function(){
  var protocol = 'http://';
  var domain = 'www.mydomain.com';
  var base = '/api/';

  return {
    category:               protocol + domain + base + 'category/',
    home:                   protocol + domain + base +  'home/',
    products:               protocol + domain + base + 'products/'
  }

})()
);
```